# How to add a self signed trusted root authority in Opera?

Tags: https, opera

I use fiddler core proxy server for my .net application to monitor https requests. I found ways to add my self-signed certificate authority from fiddler for IE and Firefox programatically or by command-line tools. However how can I do the same for Opera browser? I found that opera stores its certificate in *opcacrt6.dat* file located at C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera in Windows 7. Is there a way to add my certificate authority file to it using any tools or code?

Please note that I don't want to do it in the conventional way via the UI of opera. I want to do it programatically or by using command-lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera uses a custom binary format for a lot of their files; I believe the certificate store uses the [generic binary format](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/#generic), and hopefully by looking through that (and what adding the certificate through the UI adds) you can work out what you need to do to mutate it externally.